# Confused about Backtracking?

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

I'm trying to solve this [Leetcode Question](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-watch/description/) but I'm getting an error where I'm exceeding the time limit.

```
class Solution:  

def readBinaryWatchHelper(self,hours, minutes, num, pastHours, pastMinutes):
    if num == 0:
        hour, minute = sum(pastHours), sum(pastMinutes)
        if self.isValidTime(hour, minute):
            time = str(hour) + ":" + str(minute).zfill(2)
            self.times.add(time)
    else:
        for i in minutes:
            cMinutesTemp = list(minutes)
            pMinutesTemp = list(pastMinutes)
            pMinutesTemp.append(i)
            cMinutesTemp.remove(i)
            if self.isValidTime(sum(pastHours), sum(pMinutesTemp)):
                self.readBinaryWatchHelper(hours, cMinutesTemp, num - 1, pastHours, pMinutesTemp)    
        for i in hours:
            cHoursTemp = list(hours)
            pHoursTemp = list(pastHours)
            pHoursTemp.append(i)
            cHoursTemp.remove(i)
            if self.isValidTime(sum(pHoursTemp), sum(pastMinutes)):
                self.readBinaryWatchHelper(cHoursTemp, minutes, num - 1, pHoursTemp, pastMinutes)


@staticmethod
def isValidTime(hours, minutes):
    if hours < 12 and minutes < 60:
        return True
    return False

def readBinaryWatch(self, num):
    self.times = set()
    hChoices = [1,2,4,8]
    mChoices = [1,2,4,8,16,32]
    self.readBinaryWatchHelper(hChoices[::-1], mChoices[::-1], num, [],[])
    return list(self.times)
```

That's the solution I've written up using Backtracking. I was hoping I could get feedback on why it's too slow? One of the valid solutions is just getting all the combinations of hours from 0 - 12 and minutes from 0 - 60 and checking the sum of the bits to see if they add up to the correct sum. I'm confused as to how that solution is faster than mine? Shouldn't mine be faster due to the "tree pruning"? Thanks guys.

Comment: your class Solution contains nothing. You should add some functions inside to actually do something.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thanks for the response! That’s actually just how Leetcode formats it. So I just copied and pasted my code from their client, so the code works fine in that it passes the majority of the test cases. It’s just that it’s too slow when the sum = 8, so I was hoping someone could look at my algorithm and tell me why it’s too slow. Thanks!

Comment: Leetcode formats the functions inside a class at the same indentation level as the class definition? Then how does python know which functions are inside the class and which ones outside?

Comment: Maybe having so many list in memory can have an effect on performance. Also although recursion looks cool, its not  cheap it need the allocation of a new stack frame. Why not use a simpler solution that calculate how many bits make up a number. Do this for hours and minutes...

Comment: To make it faster, instead of passing on list  you could just pass on numbers. Just using bit operators you can do similar operations you have with Append and remove.

Comment: You don't need all the fancy but slow recursive and "tree working" stuff. It's just a simple loop from 0 to 2^10 - convert each number to binary, check if it represents a valid time and contains the expected number of 1's.

Comment: I want to get one of those watches.

Comment: That was my first thought as well

Answer (score 0):

A solution w/o backtracking but using itertools and list comp would be:

```
class Solution:
    def readBinaryWatch(self, num):
        """
        :type num: int
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        from itertools import combinations,  product
        hhmin = min(num,3)+1 # only generate at much as needed
        mmmin = min(num,5)+1 # only generate as much as needed
        nBits = [1,2,4,8,16,32]

        # {0: ['0'], 1: ['1','2','4','8'], 2: ['3','5','9','6','10'], 3: ['7','11']} for>2 
        h = { bitCount: list(str(sum(x)) for x in combinations(nBits,bitCount) 
                          if sum(x) < 12) for bitCount in range(hhmin)}

        m = { bitCount: list(str(sum(x)).zfill(2) for x in combinations(nBits,bitCount) 
                          if sum(x) < 60) for bitCount in range(mmmin)}

        ranges = ((h[subl[0]],m[subl[1]]) for subl in (x for x in product(range(num + 1),
                          range(num + 1)) if sum(x) == num and x[0]<hhmin and x[1]<mmmin))

        return ["{0}:{1}".format(hh,mm) for (hhhh,mmmm) in ranges 
                                        for hh in hhhh for mm in mmmm]
```

Test with:

```
s = Solution()
for n in range(8):
    print(s.readBinaryWatch(n))
    print()
```

It dials in between 55ms and 64ms depending on whatever between different submits. According to the page this reaches 77% - there are some much shorter and more elegnant solutions. You can inspect some of them once you submit one. Yours unfortunately does not run at all, recursion needs recursive which seems to be too slow.

Funny enough the "brute force" `if.. elif .. elif ... else` with prefabbed lists is below 50% - just had to try it ;)